# Change text color of PopupMobile

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, popup, color

I am facing the problem that with some mobile Browsers like DolphinHD and Android Browser

that the browser makes the text color white, and the background is also white.

So i want to change the textcolor - or the background color but there's no such thing defined in the documentation.

http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/jav...opupmobile.htm

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Did you checked this with Firefox browser for Android ? & if possible please provide your code in JS Fiddle..thanks

Comment: I dont want to do it with Firefox browser, and yes i checked that. But the dojo toolbox doesnt work good with firefox.

Comment: that's true fact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example you posted it tells you to include to css files.  Just open up those css files and edit those styles that you want changed.  To determine what the styles are that need change or to test your changes I would recommend Firebug which is a plugin.  Once installed you could just right click and Inspect Element to determine that css classes your need to change to get the desired styles.

Comment: In the example the only thing they can change is the titlePane, pointer top pointerdown, and navigationbar.. But not the content of the PopupMobile. Do you know how i can change this is css?

Comment: The class "content" in the popup.css.  Just create that class inside of the style tags in the head section of the page, then make the changes that you want.

Comment: Nevermind, already figured it out. I got it with the element inspector in Google Chrome. But thanks for your help.